# Проблема с кодировкой на smtp

Tags: кодировка, php, smtp, mysql

Есть скрипт, который отправляет на эмейл уведомление, приходят уведомления у виде кракозябр вместо русского текста.

utf-8 без ВОМ стоит в `notepad++`, `mysql` таблицы utf-8, в РНР файлах везде указывается utf-8, так что не на сайте не в базе проблем с кодировкой нет, вот на эмейл приходят кракозябры кроме темы письма, содержание письма и вывод с mysql в письме содержит вот такие забавные символы `п╢я─п╟п╟п╟п╟п╟я│я┌п╣ я▀п╡п╟п╡п╟`

```
function email($to, $subject, $body) {
mail($to, $subject, $body, 'From: mail@mail.ru');
}
function register_user($query) {

array_walk($query, 'array_sanitize');
$query['password']= md5($query['password']);

$fields = '`' . implode('`, `',array_keys($query)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $query) . '\'';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
email($query['email'], 'активация аккаунта', "приветствуем" . $query['first_name'] . "\n\nпройдите по следущей ссылке для завершения регистрации :\n\n ".PATH."www/activate.php?email=" . $query['email'] . "&email_code=".$query['email_code'] ."\n\n- ");
}
```

Активация аккаунта - приходит в нормальном виде, все остальное содержание это неизвестные науке символы

Answer (score 2):

Символы эти науке очень даже известны: это UTF-8, интерпретируемая как KOI8-R. А читается письмо так, потому что его отправляющий не знает, что в письмах нужно указывать чарсет.

Comment: какой именно 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
<meta charset="UTF-8">
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
если точнее то какую из них?

Comment: Заголовок, который описан в RFC-822, и который устанавливается как в примере номер 2 раздела "функция mail()" справочного руководства по PHP :) Как-то так:

    mail($to,$subj,$text,'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8');

Comment: mail($to,$subj,$text,'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8'); так письмо вообще не приходит

mail($to, $subject, $body, 'From: mail@mail.ru','Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8'); так кракозябры никуда не исчезают

Comment: все решилась проблема надо было ANSI в notepad++ в одном месте поставить

Comment: Вы что, копипастите пример, который я дал, прямо как есть - с переменными $to, $subj, $text?

Comment: так я и отправлял как есть, но без  'From: mail@mail.ru' ничего не приходит на мыло

Answer (score 0):

Без указания чарсетов, просто конвертировать кириллицу в php в кодировку KOI8-U:

```
$msg_koi8 = iconv('utf-8','windows-1251',$msg);
```